# Is it a chord? Same note different pitches

Tags: harmony

Is playing the keyboard notes on different pitches example c5,c6,c7, simultaneously from the white keys. a chord? Pardon for my English

Answer (score 1):

No, it's called *unison*. A chord needs to have 3 different note names in it. (Some agree that two only constitutes a chord).